# How to set texture to CALayer in ios?

Tags: ios, calayer

How texture(like below) image can be applied to calayer with opacity levels like combining texture and calayer image?

[Sample texture](https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRrMAJEJDOSunhdyDY-oqEgcqHIoan5Zaj5V5V4dAFREXSgf0vx)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
UIImage *yourImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yourTextureImage"];
self.yourView.layer.contents = (__bridge id) yourImage.CGImage;
```

**EDIT** Try this add sublayer on existing layer.It will give you idea how to do that.

```
//It will draw some circle
int radius = 30.0;
    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 20.0, 20.0) cornerRadius:0];
    UIBezierPath *circlePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 2.0*radius, 2.0*radius) cornerRadius:radius];
    [path appendPath:circlePath];
    [path setUsesEvenOddFillRule:YES];

    CAShapeLayer *fillLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    fillLayer.path = path.CGPath;
    fillLayer.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd;
    fillLayer.fillColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    fillLayer.opacity = 0.7;
    [self.view.layer addSublayer:fillLayer];
```

You can also try setting mask

```
       [self.view.layer setMask:fillLayer];
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried it; my image in calayer is like a png, it has transparent parts. Above code replace the texture to the background of the calayer. Is there any way to set it only the image?

Comment: what do you mean by that-set it only the image and what you want to show in transparent parts.Can you please elaborate what you want to achieve?

Comment: It makes it like this : http://oi58.tinypic.com/2uz6zif.jpg the background is already textured :(

Comment: You can draw anything on `CALayer` but as you showed image it little bit clumsy to make that drawing.I have edited answer it will draw circle and you can set opacity or anything.Have a look

Answer (score 0):

I think, if I am not mistaken, you need to use CALayer's mask property to achieve the required result.

Please try the following

```
 //create mask layer
 CALayer *maskLayer = [CALayer layer];
 maskLayer.frame = self.imageView.bounds;
 UIImage *maskImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Your image"];
 maskLayer.contents = (__bridge id)maskImage.CGImage;

 //apply mask to image layer
 self.imageView.layer.mask = maskLayer;
```