# Unable to compute Light Probes in SceneKit Editor

Tags: scenekit

I've been testing light probes to see if I could reproduce similar lighting results as Apple's Badger demo, but for whatever reason I'm unable to compute light probes in SceneKit Editor.

I'm unsure as to what the requirements are to compute light probes, if I could get some clarification on that would be great.

I'm going to list what I've tried so far to get light probes to compute.

I used the example from SceneKit's documentation, placing objects next to a colored walls. I made a grid of light probes around the objects and walls.

Lights:

Tried all light types in static mode and dynamic.
Tried with and without image based lighting.
Also tried changing light baking options for Direct/Indirect lighting.
Toggled Shadows for lights as well.

Materials:

Tried Phong and Physically Based.
For physically based material tried setting self illumination to black and to nil for objects (not walls).

Nodes:

Set object movability flags to true. (not walls)

Here's a screenshot from the editor of how I positioned the objects in the scene. I removed all the other lights from the scene to make the screenshot look a bit less cluttered.

[image]

I think the next thing I'll try is to compute the light probes using ModelIO, hopefully I can get some results.

Update 1:

I tried to share as many details as possible but after thinking it over I feel sharing the scene file itself would provide a lot of helpful details I didn't think of.

I removed all static/dynamic lights in the scene, only geometry and probes are in the scene. To test the scene, add your own lights, go to last tab in the SceneKit Editor and click "Compute all probes", then run on your device of choice.

Scene File Link:
[lightprobe_test.scn](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vyegne7m8e383o6/lightprobe_test.scn?dl=0)

Update 2:

I just wanted to show a screenshot of what I'm trying to achieve with light probes. This screenshot shows a scene with all static objects with lighting information baked into their textures. With light probes I'm hoping to achieve similar results but for dynamic objects in the scene.

[image]

Update 3:

I've been testing light probe baking in ModelIO. So far I've been able to use the MDLAsset class method placeLightProbes(withDensity:heuristic:using:) to place light probes in a grid pattern, couldn't get the second placement option working. But I am pretty happy I got this method working, now I don't have to spend years placing probes all over the scene.

I did find something odd though, after exporting the scene file and examining it in Xcode I noticed the new light probes created by ModelIO were really large compared to SceneKit's light probes. Not sure if that will cause any problems, appears to be just a cosmetic issue.

[image]

I attempted to bake probes with lighting information from the scene using the MDLLightProbe init?(textureSize:forLocation:lightsToConsider:objectsToConsider:reflectiveCubemap:irradianceCubemap:) method. But every time I ran the method the app would crash. I took a screenshot from the thread where the crash occurred.

[image]

So that's where I'm at currently, going to get some rest and try some more tomorrow. Thanks for reading.

Final Update:

After a lot of testing and help from the community I finally found out why I wasn't able to compute light probes in the SceneKit Editor. In order to compute light probes your mac needs to support Metal. Unfortunately that counts my mac mini 2011 model out. But I am due for an upgrade, this could be my excuse to do that 8).

[List of Macs that support Metal](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205073)

Comment: You might be the first person to do this since WWDC! Is there any evidence Apple did the baking in SceneKit? I'd kind of assumed they did it in an external, 3rd party renderer of a 3D modelling app. This assumption was based on them not showing how to do the baking, and light baking not working in Xcode for as long as I've tried pushing that button.

Comment: As far as I could tell studying their example code and scn files from the badger demo, I'd say you're correct about them baking the lightmaps for static objects in a 3d modeling app. Currently I'm able to use SceneKit Editor's baking features, both lightmap and ao. If you're still having issues with that just let me know I'll try my best to help. Without going into too much detail I find that it is better to bake lightmaps/ao in dedicated 3d apps, both for quality and performance reasons. But I do believe Apple used SceneKit/ModelIO to bake lighting information into probes for dynamic objects.

Comment: Other than curiosity, I have no interest in baking in Xcode/SceneKit. And it seems Apple shares my disinterest ;) I'm a 3ds Max and 3rd party renderers nutter. But I may have other questions for you about SceneKit at various points. Like how to get CALayers working as textures...

Comment: Not sure if this answers your question completely, but hopefully it helps [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24984634/how-to-set-texture-to-calayer-in-ios)

Comment: Well I don't think they are disinterested, I just feel like they have a lot on their plate and their doing the best they can. I mean I still can't believe members from the SceneKit team take time out of their day to answer our questions. I think overall SceneKit is pretty awesome and is improving every year. I'm really looking forward to this next WWDC.

Comment: What happen when you click on "compute all probes" in the scene inspector (last inspector on the right)? or if you click "compute probe" in the probe inspector? what if you change the background color to let's say a red color and recompute the probes?

Comment: If you watch the WWDC 2016 SceneKit session video, you will hear them talk about a tool they created for this game to convert units and place light probes.

Comment: @Toyos, I tried what you recommended and got the same results. Whenever I click on "Compute all probes" or compute individual probes I can see on the right side of the Xcode progress bar (top mid) briefly show a grey circle with a X in the middle and then disappear. So it looks like it tries to compute the probes and stops immediately.

Comment: @Karl, yea I saw that video session as well, I was under the impression the tool was mainly for probe placement, but maybe they used the custom tool to compute probes too, that's a possibility. But regardless, I'll try to focus my efforts on the tools I have access to.

Comment: I downloaded the attached scene and I'm able to compute the probes with Xcode 8.1 and Sierra 10.12.2. It takes a couple of seconds to update all the probes. What is your config? @karl: we indeed developed a little tool (using public APIs) but just to place the probes along the track in the wwdc 2016 demo.

Comment: @Toyos Thanks for testing it, glad to hear it's working for you. So the problem must be on my end. I'm running Sierra 10.12.1 and Xcode 8.2. I'll try upgrading Sierra to 10.12.2 and downgrading Xcode to 8.1 to match your configuration.

Comment: @Phi, what version of macOS are you running Xcode on? Baking light probes will only work on Sierra because it needs that version of Metal to run, this may be the cause of what you are seeing.

Comment: @Sebastion I'm currently running macOS Sierra 10.12.2 and Xcode 8.2. So far I've tested Xcode 8.2 and 8.1, next I'm going to try Xcode 8.0. If it's still not working I plan to backup my Mac and do a clean install to see if I can get it working. I'm running on a Mac Mini (mid 2011) 2.5GHz Intel Core i5 AMD Radeon HD 6630M, in case you needed to know. If I can't get it to work after the last step (wipe/clean macOS install) It could be an issue with my specific configuration, so I'll submit a support ticket. But thanks for taking the time to check out my post.

Comment: @Sebastion After performing a wipe/clean macOS install I wasn't able to get it working. But you said something important I didn't consider before, you said Metal is needed for this operation to work. So I looked up Mac computers that support Metal and sure enough my mac isn't on the list. It's good to finally know why baking light probes wasn't working for me. My mac mini is pretty dated so it's understandable.